# How to create List<Double> fromapache's common math DescriptiveStatistics<Double>?

Tags: java, arrays, statistics, apache-commons-math

I have a variable `DescriptiveStatistics stats` from which I would like to create `Double` array. Using the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics;
//...
DescriptiveStatistics stats;
//...
Arrays.asList(stats.getValues())
```

I get `List<double[]>` not `List<Double>`.
`stats.getValues()` returns `double[]`.

How can I fix that and get a `List<Double>` from this `DescriptiveStatistics` ?

Comment: It depends what `stats.getValues()` returns?

Comment: You can use Guava predicates and Collection2.transform your domain list to a different list

Comment: @GriffeyDog How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per method signature of [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) that returns a List of type as passed in arguments.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

---

For example:

```
double[] array=new double[]{1,2,3};
List<double[]> list=Arrays.asList(array); // Here T is `double[]` List of size 1

...

double[][] array = new double[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
List<double[]> list=Arrays.asList(array); // Here T is `double[]` List of size 2

...

List<Double> list=Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0,3.0); // Here T is double List of size 3
```

---

#### Root cause:

Since array itself is an Object and in your case `double[]` is treated as single object, not as array of double as per *Generic* hence `List<double[]>` is returned instead of `List<Double>`.

#### Solution 1

You can solve it by simple classic code:

```
double[] array = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (double d : array) {
    list.add(d);
}
```

#### Solution 2

Simply change the return type of the method `stats.getValues()` from `double[]` to `Double[]`

```
Double[] array = new Double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Comment: I ended up needing to iterate over the array (Solution 1).

Comment: Great, Go ahead. classic is all type favorite. :)